# Property related to path connected

Tags: general-topology, equivalence-relations, connectedness

Let $a=(a_1,\dots, a_k)$ and $b=(b_1,\dots, b_k)$ be points in $k$-dimentional space $\mathbb{R}^k$. A $\textit{path}$ from $a$ to $b$ is a continuous function on the unit interval $[0,1]$ with values in $\mathbb{R}^k$, a function $X: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$, sending $t \mapsto X(t)=(x_1(t),\dots, x_k(t))$, such that $X(0)=a$ and $X(1)=b.$ If $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$ and if $a$ and $b$ are in $S$, define $a \sim b$ if $a$ and $b$ can be joined by a path lying entirely in $S$.

A subset $S$ is *path connected* if $a \sim b$ for any two points $a$ and $b$ in S. I would like to show that every subset $S$ is partitioned into path-connected subsets with the property that two points in different subsets cannot be connected by a path in $S$.

Comment: Can you show $\sim$ is an equivalence relation? Do you know the correspondence between equivalence relations on a set $S$ and partitions of $S$?

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you just want to consider path connectedness in the subspace topology of a set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: @dls I showed that it is an equivalence relation. Yes: an equivalence relation determines a partition on X no ?

Comment: @AndrewD Yes Andrew

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisRossignol And the partitions are the equivalence classes, in this case called *path components*.

Comment: @dls Yes I do know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you show that path-connectedness constitutes an equivalence relation on $S$ by defining $a\sim b$ if there exists a path in $S$ joining $a$ and $b$, then you are done.

If $f$ is a path joining $a$ and $b$, and $g$ is a path joining $b$ and $c$, define $g\cdot f$ to be the path
$$t\mapsto\begin{cases}
f(2t), &\text{ if } 0\le t\le 1/2 \\
g(2t-1),&\text{ if } 1/2\le t\le 1
\end{cases}$$
Can you show that $g\cdot f$ is continuous?

The proof of symmetry and reflexivity is equally easy.

The equivalence classes of $S$ under $\sim$ are called *path-components*.

If $a,b$ are two points in the path-component $P,$ then they can be joined by a path $f$. This path must lie entirely in $P,$ for if $f(s)=y$ for some $y\notin P,$ and $s\in(0,1)$ then we could restrict $f$ to a path joining $a$ and $y$.

Comment: I already showed that it is an equivalence relation. Could you just write as an answer how to conclude ?

Comment: Then whats your question?

Comment: I am asking how to show that every subset $S$ is partitioned into path-connected subsets with the property that two points in different subsets cannot be connected by a path in $S$. I already showed that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. How do we continue from there. Thank you

Comment: @StenH. So we can't have both a and b. And the partition is deduced from the fact that there is an equivalence relation defined on S

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisRossignol: yes the partition is induced by the equivalence relation.